# Restore of database failing due to pending requests

Tags: sql-server, restore, sql-server-2014

I am taking a backup of a database from one of our servers and I am placing it on my laptop so that I can run it locally.

I have tried to restore the database on to my laptop and I get the following error message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The transaction operation cannot be
>   performed because there are pending requests working on this
>   transaction. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended).

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Run SP_WHoISACtive from Adam Mechanics and see what's the current status, is the query or session running, suspended, runnable, blocked etc..?

Comment: where you are getting this error when restoring DB or when you perform any operation using EF

Comment: @TangoKilo, Have you sure about you are restoring the database to same version & level of SQL Server database. Or Again take full backup and try to restore.

Comment: Restore DB itself does not generate that error message you provided. It is usually generated because some app code or EF has multiple queries/transactions on the same connection. Please provide details on how you performed the restore and the correct error message.